# Generating Random Number AVR without seed

Tags: avr, random-seed, avr-studio4

I writing an application in AVR Studio 4 which generates random numbers and outputs them on a seven segment display. At the moment i am using a seed, the seed value then gets randomized and the value output. This method obviously produces the same random number sequence (and displays the same sequence) every time the program is run. Is there an alternate method i can use which does not use a seed and as such does not start the program with the same number each time, allowing for different random numbers.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an analog input on the device you're targeting?

Comment: Yes, Port A serves as the analog inputs to the A/D Converter. Sorry forgot to mention im using ATmega 8535.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time the microcontroller starts up it is seeing exactly the same internal state as any other time it starts up. This means its output will always be the same regardless of any algorithm you might use.

The only way to get it to produce different behaviour is to somehow modify its state at startup by introducing some external information or by storing state between startups. Some ideas for how to do the first option might be to measure the duration of a user key press (if your system has buttons) or sensing a temperature or other external input and using this to seed the algorithm. However the simplest option is probably to just store a counter in EEPROM that is incremented after each startup and use this to generate the seed.

Comment: The external input can just be the least significant bit(s?) of the ADC, sampled a few times in a row. If it's not connected to anything it'll be pretty random.